# What type of serialization is that?

Tags: serialization, encoding

I am wondering about the type of encoded string like that:

```
a:2{s:3{"xyz"}, s:0{""}}
```

and is there any viewer for it like JSON viewer etc...

Comment: Where did you find it?

Comment: I saw it in WP plug in database record

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks extremely similar to [PHP's native serialization format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php). The program:

```
print serialize([ "xyz" => "" ]);
```

will output:

```
a:1:{s:3:"xyz";s:0:"";}
```

Your sample has a couple of extra braces, and uses different punctuation in a few places. These don't make any sense; they would not be accepted by `deserialize()`.